# Why can instantiating one instance of a class change the result of a method called on another instance?

Tags: python, class, oop, static-methods, class-method

When i was trying to use example from textbook and trying to
rearrange some lines of code for executing,
I found the result was not what I expected.

There is a ''class'' which looks like below.

```
class Circle:
    """This class creates circle"""
    pi = 3.14159
    all_circles = []

    def __init__(self, radius):
        self.radius = radius
        self.__class__.all_circles.append(self)
    
    def area(self):
        return self.__class__.pi * (self.radius ** 2)

    @staticmethod
    def total_area():
        total =0
        for circle in Circle.all_circles:
            total += circle.area()
        return total    

    @classmethod
    def total_area2(cls):
        total = 0
        for circle in cls.all_circles:
            total += circle.area()
        return total
```

When I execute it.....

```
c1 = Circle(10)
c2 = Circle(15)
print(c1.__class__.total_area()) # get 1021.01675
print(c2.__class__.total_area()) # get 1021.01675
```

In my opinion,  Both c1 and c2 should be independent objects.

How do the codes cause 1021.01675 by c1 and 1021.01675 by c2

but.....

```
c1 = Circle(10)
print(c1.__class__.total_area()) # get 314.159
c2 = Circle(15)
print(c2.__class__.total_area()) # get 1021.01675
```

Do I ingnore, forget or misunderstand some concepts?

My position on this problem is that the execution should be looked like....

```
c1 = Circle(10)
c2 = Circle(15)
print(c1.__class__.total_area()) # get 314.159
print(c2.__class__.total_area()) # get 706.85775
```

and.....

```
c1 = Circle(10)
print(c1.__class__.total_area()) # get 314.159
c2 = Circle(15)
print(c2.__class__.total_area()) # get 706.85775
```

Comment: When you read the source code to `total_area()`, with the `for circle in Circle.all_circles:`, what do you _think_ it's trying to do?

Answer (score 2):

Both `c1.__class__` and `c2.__class__` is `Circle`. `total_area` is a `staticmethod`: it's basically just a function that is not tied to the class. However, internally, it iterates over `Circle.all_circles`, which is a class attribute, not an instance attribute.

When you initialize a new circle, the line `self.__class__.all_circles.append(self)` registers the circle with the class. That means that `total_area` will look at all the circles created up to that point. That's what you see in your examples.

If you want a per-circle area, use the instance method `area`.